# Is it possible to hide single quote (') in the beginning of a text in excel?

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, export

I have an application that when I click Run Report the data will be generated and exported to excel.
I posted a question regarding about a value converted to date when exporting in excel.
My first problem was that I have a data in a column Requisition No. which is the value is for example like this `08-20` but when I export it on excel it will became a date like `20-Aug`
So I put a single quote in my code for it to identify as text and not convert to date.

```
If arrColumn(intColCount2) = 29 Then
    strHTML += "<td>&#145;" & dr("vRequisition") & "</td>"
End If
```

but now it shows like this in excel

[image: Excel]

I get the output that I want for my first problem which is not to convert the value into a date.

what I'm trying to do is to hide the single quote (') at the beginning of the text in excel so that it will show only like this

```
08-20
```

is it possible to hide the single quote (') in the beginning of the text in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems not to create really Excel format workbooks but simply to create HTML and to export this HTML to Excel.

Using this approach you can use CSS [Styling Excel cells with mso-number-format](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.de/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html)  to number format the `td` as text format for Excel.

Example

```
strHTML += "<td style='mso-number-format:""\@""'>" & dr("vRequisition") & "</td>"
```